# Rate limit for Ad Reporting API

Tags: linkedin-api

For some ad reporting, I'm aiming to use LinkedIn Ad Reporting API.

In the documentation I can only find a very general article on rate limits without concrete numbers (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/api-guide/concepts/rate-limits?context=linkedin/marketing/context).

On the documentation page for the relevant API, I can't find any information either (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ads-reporting).

What is the rate limit for that API or where can I find it?

Comment: You could check from the UI  `https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps/<app-id>/usage`

Comment: Here some other resources https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/compliance/request-limits-and-patterns